# Show that ${\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+2 h)+2 f(a-h)-3 f(a)}{h^{2}}}=3f′′(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Before the proof, I have proved the limit representation of the second derivative

\begin{align}
f''(x)&=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}\\
f''(x)&=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+2 h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}\\
f''(x)&=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+2 h)-f(x+h)-f(x+h)+f(x)}{h}}{h}\\
f''(x)&=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+2 h)-f(x+h)-f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^{2}}\\
f''(x)&=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+2 h)-2 f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}
\end{align}

This formula looks very similar to the limit expression of the second derivative，So, how to prove this equation?

Comment: You can use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Your second equation requires justification. Be careful with limits.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that $f''(a)$ exists, otherwise the formula makes no sense. (This should have been mentioned in the problem, though.)

So we can apply Taylor's theorem; cf. the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Thus there is a real function $g(x)$ such that
$$f(x)= f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2 + g(x)(x-a)^2$$
and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)=0$.

Put $x=a+2h$ and $x=a-h$ to obtain
$$f(a+2h)= f(a)+f'(a)\cdot 2h+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)\cdot 4h^2 + g(a+2h)\cdot 4h^2$$
$$f(a-h)= f(a)+f'(a)\cdot (-h)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)\cdot h^2 + g(a-h)\cdot h^2$$

Thus the numerator is

$f(a+2h)+2f(a-h)-3f(a)=$
$f(a)+2hf'(a)+2h^2f''(a) + 4h^2g(a+2h) +$
$+2f(a)-2hf'(a)+h^2f''(a) + 2h^2g(a-h)-3f(a) =$
$3h^2f''(a)+4h^2g(a+2h)+ 2h^2g(a-h)$.
If you divide by $h^2$, you obtain $3f''(a)+4g(a+2h)+ 2g(a-h)$.
Taking the limit $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}$ yields $3f''(a)$.